# Add csv data to leaflet map

Tags: javascript, html, csv, leaflet

I have a leaflet map that should show some locations in Germany in the form of points. I have tried in the code below to add the csv file I have stored locally in my system but I do not see any points on my map. I have a data that has Latitude and Longitude in it. I am using these two columns to display them on map but I have no success. I would really appreciate if somebody can tell me what is wrong with my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
            integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
            crossorigin=""/>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
            integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
            crossorigin=""></script>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/papaparse@5.3.0/papaparse.min.js"></script>
            <style>
                #mapid { height: 880px; }
            </style>
            <title>OSM and Leaflet</title>
            
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="mapid"></div>
            
            <script>
                const map = L.map('mapid').setView([50.875, 9.141], 6);

                const attribution = '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';

                const tileUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
                const tiles = L.tileLayer(tileUrl, {attribution});
                tiles.addTo(map);
                //const marker = L.marker([50.875, 9.141]).addTo(map);

                $.get('./data.csv', function(csvString) {

                // Use PapaParse to convert string to array of objects
                var data = Papa.parse(csvString, {header: true, dynamicTyping: true}).data;

                // For each row in data, create a marker and add it to the map
                // For each row, columns `Latitude`, `Longitude`, and `Title` are required
                for (var i in data) {
                var row = data[i];

                var marker = L.marker([row.Latitude, row.Longitude], {
                opacity: 1
                }).bindPopup(row.Title);
      
                marker.addTo(map);
                }

                });

                /*marker.bindPopup('<h1>hello</h1>');
                marker.on('mouseover', function (e) {
                this.openPopup();
                });
                
                marker.on('mouseout', function(event){
                marker.closePopup();
                });*/
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

[image: This is how my data looks like]

Comment: Any errors on your browser's console?

Comment: Yes, I get the following error messages:

1) Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/8954/OneDrive%20-%20Expleo%20France/Dokumente/Expleo%20Map/data.csv' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, edge, https, chrome-untrusted.

2) Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED